# Cant Inject same instance to multiple Verticles using Guice and Vertx to

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, vert.x

I have 3 vertx verticles.

I created class AImpl which implements class A as follows

```
 @Singleton
public class AImpl implements A {


    public LocationServiceImpl() {
        System.out.println("initiated once");

    }

 public void doSomething(){..}
```

Verticle 1 looks like this:

```
public class MyVerticle1 extends AbstractVerticle {
...
 @Inject
    private A a;


 @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> fut) {
 Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector()).injectMembers(this);
  a.doSomething(..);

..}
```

MyVerticle2 and MyVerticle3 looks the same.

Guice code:

```
public class AppInjector extends AbstractModule {


    public AppInjector() {
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure() {   
 bind(A.class).to(AImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);

    }
```

Now when I run vertx I can see that I get 3 different  instances of AImpl:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StarterVerticle.class);
        ClusterManager mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager();
        VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions().setClusterManager(mgr);
        Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                Vertx vertx = res.result();
                vertx.deployVerticle(new MyVerticle1());
                vertx.deployVerticle(new MyVerticle2());
                vertx.deployVerticle(new MyVerticle3());
                logger.info("Vertx cluster started!");
            } else {
                logger.error("Error initiating Vertx cluster");
            }
        });
```

console:

```
2015-09-15 16:36:15,611 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO   - Vertx cluster started!
initiated once
initiated once
initiated once
```

What am I abusing with guice? why I dont get the same AImpl instance?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using guice the wrong way. You are creating the MyVerticle instances via new and create the injector inside their start message. Thus you end up with 3 injectors, each holding a singleton.

You have to create the injector once in your main() method and then let guice handle the creation of the MyVerticles:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(....);
...
vertx.deployVerticle(injector.getInstance(MyVerticle1.class);
```

now the injector creates only one instance for AImpl and reuses it for all `@Inject AImpl` locations. Remove the injectors from your start methods completely.

2 rules of thumb when working with guice:

1. avoid using `new`
2. try to use only one single injector located in your main() method

Comment: thanks for your response. could you show a concrete example I am not sure how I should create my verticles without the new and How I should define tham on Guice

Comment: Does accepting mean you figured it out or should I still provide an example?

Comment: I figured it out. I would just like to have your explanation how your answer actually solve it? Guess I missed something with my understanding and Guice. thank you.

Comment: The injector you create via Guice.create basically holds a map of types and instances. So your singleton instance is not available in other injectors. As you created one injector per verticle, they didn't share anything. Now you are creating one injector on application root that then can manage instance generation and scopes for all of your classes.

Comment: Is it best practice to have a global Guice injector or injector per verticle instance? I assume injector per verticle instance should be fine as verticles are self contained, you have a 'singleton-per-verticle' instead of global singleton.

Comment: @DavidFernandez thats a good point, but i think it has much overhead doing this like that. Maybe there is a solution having a SingletonPerVerticle-Scope (-Annotation). Do you know, if something like this exists?